# Problems installing new SSD in MacBookPro mid-2014

Tags: macbook-pro, install, ssd, recovery, big-sur

Long story but I have a MBP 11,1 mid-2014 which is one of the models that Apple has recently revoked Big Sur support for due to bricking issues (https://mrmacintosh.com/big-sur-11-0-1-20b50-released-to-block-install-for-2013-14-13-mbpros/).

I also have a new OWC SSD to upgrade storage to 1T, but it requires High Sierra or later to recognise the disk.

I installed the new SSD and tried alt-cmd-r recovery to install the new OS however the recovery only gives me the option to install Big Sur, when I attempt an install it says it cannot download the files it needs.

I tried the alt-r recovery which gives me the option to install the original OS which was Mavericks. I can't do this because it won't support the new SSD.

So I am currently booting from the original SSD with Catalina installed externlly until I figure something out. My end goal is either Catalina or Big Sur installed on the new internal SSD drive.

My options i think are:

1. wait for apple to add back support to MBP 11,1 for Big Sur (fingers crossed).
2. try to somehow install Catalina on my new SSD (not sure how to do this though without going via Mavericks).

Any bright ideas? Thanks!

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/309400#309400

Comment: Thanks -- I'm using the UK app store (I think) so the links to download the installers don't work. Is the only option switching to the US store?

Comment: The links ought to redirect to your local App Store & open the App Store app (mine does & I'm UK too).

Comment: I am trying https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-catalina/id1466841314?ls=1&mt=12 from the link -- i select the app store to redirect to, then it says "cannot connect to app store" which is v odd bc I am able to browse the store no problem..

Comment: Are you signed into the app store? Works just fine for me here. Even though my Mac won't actually install Catalina, it will find it in the store but refuse to install it if asked. Same for all the others with direct links that used to be in your purchase history. Now there's no 'purchase' required.

Comment: Yeah signed in -- option to sign out is there too. :(

Comment: Okay update -- I read somewhere else it had to be Safari used to open the link... This now gives me the option in app store !

Comment: Ah, OK, cool. I never use anything other than Safari so I'd never noticed. I've added a note to that effect on my answer.